Why don't we write complex numbers as $a i^{b}$?
Given that $a i^b$ = $ae^{\frac{\pi}{2}bi}$, why do we not prefer to write complex numbers in the form $a i^{b}$ instead of the usual polar form?
Intuitively, fractional powers are a much simpler operation to think about compared to complex powers of $e$:

$i$ can be thought of as a quarter turn degree rotation of the complex plane
$i^{0.5}$ can be thought of as an eighth of a turn, because composing two of them gives us a quarter turn: $i^{0.5} \times i^{0.5} = i$
Similarly, other fractional powers $i^x$ represent $x/4$ of the way to a full turn. This can be defined without relying on exponentials by defining $i^\frac{a}{b}$ to be the $a$th power of the $b$th root of $i$, and extending to reals by taking the limit.

Is there an advantage to involving $e$ and $\pi$ in this?

The polar form gives the angle and radius explicitly. That's extremely convenient.

We still get the radius in the $r i^\theta$ form, as well as the angle (but measured in quarter turns instead of radians). Defining a constant $j = i^{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ could still allow us to write $r j^\theta$ where $\theta$ is in radians, without involving $e$ at all.

The problem is that $(a^b)^c\neq a^{bc}$ in general,  for complex numbers, so you have to cover gross questions of complex numbers.


This can be defined without relying on exponentials by defining $i^\frac{a}{b}$ to be the $a$th power of the $b$th root of $i$, and extending to reals by taking the limit.

This is a good idea but it doesn't work. Over the complex numbers there are $b$ different $b^{th}$ roots of $i$ so this is ambiguous. Which one do you choose? How do you know your collection of choices defines a continuous function?
(Over $\mathbb{R}$ we resolve this issue by only defining exponentiation with a non-negative base, in which case we can simply always choose the unique non-negative $b^{th}$ root, but there's no obvious analogue of that here. What you'd like to do here is choose the unique $b^{th}$ root in the upper right quadrant of the complex plane with smallest imaginary part (closest to the $x$-axis) but the work that would go into arguing that this makes $i^t$ continuous seems exactly as hard if not harder than any of the usual developments of the complex exponential.)
When you write $i^{\frac{a}{b}} = e^{ i\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{a}{b}}$ you have implicitly chosen a particular collection of $b^{th}$ roots of $i$ for all $b$, namely $i^{\frac{1}{b}} = e^{ \frac{i \pi}{2b} }$. Your ability to make that choice in a way that actually gives a continuous function exactly depends on the usual complex exponential so this does not give an independent definition.
And the $\pi$ is there whether you want it to be or not. Try computing the derivative $\frac{d}{dt} i^t$!
The $e$, on the other hand, is arguably a red herring. The thing that's appearing here is not really $e$ as such but the complex exponential function $\exp(z)$, which can be defined without any reference to $e$ and arguably it is much more conceptual and intuitive to do so. See e.g. this answer.
In general we avoid talking about exponentiation $z^w$ if both the base and the exponent are complex, because this is not a single-valued function. It can be "defined" as $\exp(w \log z)$ (there is no way to escape talking about the exponential function here), which works fine if $z > 0$ is a positive real and we always take the real logarithm, but in general (and in particular for $z = i$) $\log z$ is also multi-valued so the answer depends on a choice of branch of the logarithm. So this is all very messy and annoying.
Meanwhile $\exp(z)$ is a perfectly well-behaved single-valued holomorphic function satisfying the nicest possible differential equation $\frac{d}{dz} \exp(z) = \exp(z)$. It doesn't get nicer than this!
